# How to access a Symfony 2 bundle configuration from outside the bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, bundle

**Please**, don't link to [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)

In fact, I already have a fully working bundle, with many configuration options. The bundle is actually configured at `app/config.yml`, on its own section. I have already implemented a ConfigurationInterface, with its TreeBuilder, and so on. And I am able to successfully inject the config in the bundle and use it in the bundle code.

Yet, what I want to do is extremely simple, but even though I have a [fully working bundle](https://github.com/paggybrasil/PaggyBoletoBundle) published and installable using Composer, I've been playing with Symfony 2 only for a few weeks, and probably the answer is indeed ridiculously simple... but I don't know it!

**How can I access the bundle configuration from my app controller?**

For example... being this the config at `app/config.yml` (where "devices" has array prototype):

```
my_bundle:
    format: standard
    devices:
        main:
            color: yellow
            capacity: 200
```

How can I access these values from the controller of an app using the bundle?

Comment: I considered exposing the configuration from inside the bundle... but what if I wasn't the bundle author? (Plus I really don't want to change the bundle code only to accomplish this.)

Comment: And I only want to merely **read** the configuration values.

Comment: It depends how you implemented bundle's configuration builder - it prepends its parameters with a certain prefix. In your case it might be something like `my_bundle.devices`. Otherwise, could you post the code of your `DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php` ?

Comment: Hmmm, my question is pretty basic... suppose it is `my_bundle.devices`... how do I access it? What is the method call? The code: https://github.com/paggybrasil/PaggyBoletoBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/PaggyBoletoExtension.php

Comment: OMG... if only I looked at my own code! :-) `paggy_boleto.config`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole config is exposed in the parameter `paggy_boleto.config` as an nested array. To access it, in controller:

```
$config = $this->container->getParameter('paggy_boleto.config');
```

`var_dump` the config to see, how you access the entries in it.

If you need access others bundle config you have to take a look in the bundles Extension class, how they expose the config into the di container. Some bundle like yours exposes the whole config, some other bundles don't (they expose only specific parameters).

In the PaggyBaletoBundle this is the relevant [line](https://github.com/paggybrasil/PaggyBoletoBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/PaggyBoletoExtension.php#L25):

```
$container->setParameter('paggy_boleto.config', $config);
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it was simple. I've played with Symfony 2 for a week or two, then switched to Laravel + Angular.JS, now back to Symfony 2... too much concurrent threads in the head!

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you implemented bundle's configuration builder - it prepends its parameters with a certain prefix.

According to [your case](https://github.com/paggybrasil/PaggyBoletoBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/PaggyBoletoExtension.php#L25) it is `paggy_boleto.config`

Comment: +1 You really helped me, your comment right into the point made me "discover" the answer before they were posted here. I accepted Pazi's one because he wrote a detailed answer, he has only 2.8k rep while you already have 5k, et cetera. I thank YOU a lot, and I wish I could accept both answers and give you a hundred rep points. A thousand! So, the points go to Pazi, but you have my gratitude and blessings!

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters.yml for that purpose. 
and then you can easily get the things in your controller like this

```
$parameters = $this->container->getParameter('devices');
```

Comment: Indeed... @thecatontheflat pointed me to the right direction... and I already got it: `$this->container->getParameter('paggy_boleto.config');`

Comment: parameters.yml won't work, if you need to access semantic bundle configuration.